# Rails before_action that takes long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using something like this in my `Controller` class:

```ruby
before_action :do_something, only: [:new, :create]

def new
   @myModel = MyModel.new
end

def create
   @myModel = MyModel.create_with_data(params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @myModel.errors.empty?
        format.html { redirect_to @myModel, notice: 'MyModel was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @myModel }
     else
        logger.error 'MyModelController: Creating mymodel failed!'
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @myModel.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
end

def do_something
   # Very long method
end
```

Now, the problem is, that my `do_something` method takes very long to execute. If user will make mistake while creating new `myModel` field, he will need to wait for this method to execute, just to display him some error.

Let's say, that I don't want front-end validation and I can't reduce the time of `do_something` method. How can I pass somehow data from `do_something` that executed before `new` method is called, so it won't be needed to execute again before `create` method?

Comment: Could you add more information about the data you are going to pass? (size, form, etc)

Comment: you can save it to DB

Comment: Data from do_something is containing collection of big ruby objects.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using an optimistic saving approach instead. Much like how unconfirmed users are usually treated.

You insert the record in the database but set a state which denotes that it's not a full fledged record. You then update the record when it is confirmed.

It gives the user quick feedback and you can free your web process from waiting for `do_something`.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # create an Int column named status
  # make sure it has an index and defaults to 0.
  enum status: [:unverified, :verified]
end
```

So, you would do something like this in your controller:

```
def create
  # Don't do params assignment / whitelisting in your models.
  # models should not be aware of parameters.
  @my_model = MyModel.new(my_model_params) do |m|
    # This should be handled by the DB default but 
    # this is a belt and suspenders approach to be 200% sure
    # that a record does not slip through.
    m.unverified!
  end

  if @my_model.save
    MyModelVerificationJob.perform_later(@my_model)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        flash[:notice] = "We are currently verifying..."
        redirect_to :edit, @my_model
      end
      # ...
    end
  else
    # we already know something is fishy so just render the 
    # form again.
    respond_to do |format|
      # ...
    end
  end
end 

private
  def my_model_params
    params.require(:my_model).permit(...)
  end
```

This example is with Rails 5 [Active Jobs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) but you can look into Resque or Sidekiq as well.

How exactly to handle the callback from your `do_something` method depends on what kind of user interaction is required. If the user needs to correct a form for example you would cache the results from the background job and prompt the user to visit a page where they correct the form.

Comment: It's promising answer. I need to check it out.

Comment: Of course it depends on how slow `do_something` really is. If you can live with tying up your dyno for 15ms and having a slightly slow response than it might not be worth the fuss. But if it is significant you will want to look into doing it in the background instead.

Comment: edited, I used `state` in the model and `status` in the controller.